# Double iteration on mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to display unique dates of submitted surveys and place the response in a great, good, fair or bad row. I'm not sure what the problem is with this code but it returns the most recent date only.Something like this

```
SurveyDate | Great | Good | Fair | Bad
2016-09-26 | 34    | 12   | 22   | 5  
2016-08-24 | 10    | 5    | 12   | 3  

<?php
$w = "select distinct(datetime) from clientsurvey order by datetime desc";  
$zx = mysql_query($w);  
if (mysql_num_rows($zx) < 1) {  
echo "<tr><td colspan='5' style='text-align:center; color:#ff0000'>No survey records</td></tr>";  
}
$great = 0;
$good = 0;
$fair = 0;
$bad = 0;
while ($z = mysql_fetch_array($zx)) {
   $uniquedate = $z['datetime'];
   $xx = "select * from clientsurvey where datetime like '%$uniquedate%'";
   $zz = mysql_query($xx);
   while ($zx = mysql_fetch_array($zz)) {
       $clientrating = $zx['clientrating'];
       $datetime = $zx['datetime'];
       if ($clientrating === "Bad") {
        $bad++;
       }
       if ($clientrating === "Fair") {
        $fair++;
       }
       if ($clientrating === "Good") {
         $good++;
       }
       if ($clientrating === "Great") {
        $great++;
       }
    }
    echo "<tr><td>$uniquedate</td><td>$great</td><td>$good</td><td>$fair</td><td>$bad</td></tr>";
$great = 0;
$good = 0;
$fair = 0;
$bad = 0;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can actually handle this directly in MySQL using a pivot query:

```
SELECT datetime AS SurveyDate,
       SUM(CASE WHEN clientrating = 'Great' THEN 1 END) AS Great,
       SUM(CASE WHEN clientrating = 'Good'  THEN 1 END) AS Good,
       SUM(CASE WHEN clientrating = 'Fair'  THEN 1 END) AS Fair,
       SUM(CASE WHEN clientrating = 'Bad'   THEN 1 END) AS Bad
FROM clientsurvey
GROUP BY datetime
```

**PHP code:**

```
$query = "SELECT datetime AS SurveyDate,".
         "SUM(CASE WHEN clientrating = 'Great' THEN 1 END) AS Great,".
         "SUM(CASE WHEN clientrating = 'Good'  THEN 1 END) AS Good,".
         "SUM(CASE WHEN clientrating = 'Fair'  THEN 1 END) AS Fair,".
         "SUM(CASE WHEN clientrating = 'Bad'   THEN 1 END) AS Bad".
         "FROM clientsurvey".
         "GROUP BY datetime";
$result = mysql_query($query);
echo "datetime, bad, fair, good, great";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $datetime = $row['datetime'];
    $bad      = $row['Bad'];
    $fair     = $row['Fair'];
    $good     = $row['Good'];
    $great    = $row['Great'];
    echo $datetime.", ".$bad.", ".$fair.", ".$good.", ".$great;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Tim. The plan is to display the result on a php webpage. How do I go about this with your approach?

Comment: @KayodeAgbede Just iterate over the result set.  Each row will have all four ratings total for a given datetime value.

Comment: Thanks Tim. I guess my question is how do I tie each output for great,good,fair,bad to php variables that I can then format or manipulate?

Comment: You are already doing this in your code above.  Just access the columns I defined in my query and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

I didnt look at the rest of your code but this should work for multiple dates;

```
 <?php
$w = "select distinct(datetime) from clientsurvey order by datetime desc";  
$zx = mysql_query($w);  
if (mysql_num_rows($zx) < 1) {  
echo "<tr><td colspan='5' style='text-align:center; color:#ff0000'>No survey records</td></tr>";  
}
$great = 0;
$good = 0;
$fair = 0;
$bad = 0;
while ($z = mysql_fetch_array($zx)) {
$uniquedate = $z['datetime'];
$xx = "select * from clientsurvey where datetime like '%$uniquedate%'";
$zz = mysql_query($xx);
while ($zx = mysql_fetch_array($zz)) {
       $clientrating = $zx['clientrating'];
   $datetime = $zx['datetime'];
   if ($clientrating === "Bad") {
    $bad++;
   }
   if ($clientrating === "Fair") {
    $fair++;
   }
   if ($clientrating === "Good") {
     $good++;
   }
   if ($clientrating === "Great") {
    $great++;
   }
                     echo "<tr><td>$uniquedate</td><td>$great</td><td>$good</td><td>$fair</td><td>$bad</td></tr>";

$great = 0;
$good = 0;
$fair = 0;
$bad = 0;
}

 }?>
```

But maybe you should do it in the SQL like someone else suggested